# Cannot be inferred error: How to change color in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I have the following error in my code:

`The Type arguments for method x cannot be inferred from usage.Try specifying the type arguments explictly.`

These errors are indicated in Visual Studio with a 'red curly underline'.

My problem:
I can't really see the 'red curly underline' so I want to change how these errors are displayed. After going through the `Tools` - `Options`  - `Fonts and colors`, I can't seem to find anything that resembles 'red curly underline'. (Perhaps because I just can't see it there either)

Can this be configured?

**Update**
According to Richard, this is handled by the `Syntax Error` Font Color. But its value is being overwritten, probably by ReSharper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to change the `ReSharper Underline Error Highlighting` colour:

[image]

(This is in Visual Studio 2012 with ReSharper 7.1 but should be the same for other versions)

Answer (score 6):

The red-squiggle-underline can be changed with the colour (Tools | Options | General | Fonts and Colours") via the colour setting "Syntax Error".

This works since at least VS 2010 and later.

(Just successfully changed from red to yellow—I'm using a dark colour schema so it shows up effectively, but yellow doesn't carry the right "stop" meaning errors need.)

(NB. all of this without Resharper or other similar extension: it is possible that such an extension could override this setting with its own possibly hard-coded value.)

Comment: It looks like ReSharper (or something else) is overriding the setting. I already had it set to "Yellow" but it's being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I came here to find how to change that underline red row under errors. If that's the case of any other person, here it goes.

In Visual Studio 2019 go to:

- Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Syntax Error